# can't telnet localhost 25 on centos

Tags: centos, postfix

i have done to install and config the postfix but when i test to telnet

i get the result

```
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

i have try to use more way for solved the problem but can't find the solution.

the

master.cf

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#-o smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender=yes
#-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#-o broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628      inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
```

thank you

Comment: post output of `netstat -antep |grep ':25'

Comment: be careful using `0.0.0.0/8` as `mynetworks`.  If that server is externally accessible, you could potentially be an open relay for others to abuse.

Comment: @Aaron How would that open the server to abuse? There are no routable IP address in `0.0.0.0/8`.

Comment: Sorry, my mind saw `0.0.0.0/0`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should check that postfix process is running:

```
ps axu | grep master
```

Second, check what is listening to port 25:

```
netstat -apn | grep :25
```

You should get similiar output:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5690/master
```

Third, check postfix config:

```
postconf  | grep smtp_bind_address
```

It should be empty, e.g. postfix listens on all addresses:

```
smtp_bind_address =
smtp_bind_address6 =
```

Fourth, fix errors found in the steps above)

Comment: when i run second step then not give result just like close

Comment: for the third step the step give same result

Comment: It seems the postfix service is stopped.
Try 
`/etc/init.d/postfix start`
If it fails, post the output of `postfix check`

Comment: when i use postfix check still not give result

Comment: So I assume the command `/etc/init.d/postfix start` failed.
Try to start it manually by hand:
`postfix -vv start` 
and post the output.

Comment: i have post the output in my question post

Comment: Output looks good.
Please, check last lines of /var/log/maillog. It should be something useful there.
Also check /etc/postfix/master.cf.
Post the line beginning with **smtp**.

Comment: for the maillog no error result, and for the master.cf i have post on my question

Comment: Hmm. It should work then. May be you messed up something else on the server?
Let's add implicit iptables rule that permits smtp traffic:

`/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT ;
/sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --sport 25 -j ACCEPT
`

Comment: hmm. i have done add iptables rule but connection still refused